# jQuery table row selector except MVC actionlinks

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an html table with...
... some jquery code bound to the table row click

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tr = $('#RolesTable').find('tbody>tr');
    tr.bind('click', function (e) {
        code fired on table row click..
    }
}
```

...and some action links in the table for edit and delete functions

```
<td class="TablePadding">
  @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { id = item.RoleID }, new { @class = "editImg" }) 
  @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id = item.RoleID }, new { @class = "deleteImg" })
</td>
```

How can I get the jquery *not* to fire when one of the html action links/ images are clicked?

I've tried using the not() method sbut can't get it to work. e.g. amended jquery..

```
var tr = $('#RolesTable').find('tbody>tr').not("a.editImg").not("a.deleteImg");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use target property of the event object. If one of the anchors is clicked, using return, rest of the handler is not executed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tr = $('#RolesTable tbody > tr');
    tr.bind('click', function (e) {
        var $target = $(e.target);
        if ($target.is('a.editImg') || $target.is('a.deleteImg')) {
          return;
        } else {
          // code fired on table row click..
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Hi @undefined. 
I was having some trouble getting this to work until I realised I'd blindly copied in your code and the return was missing a ";"

Once rectified it's doing as it says on the tin.
Cheers :)